# Updating the same instance variables from different processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Here is a simple secinaro:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = []

    def append(self, x):
        self.foo.append(x)

    def get(self):
        return self.foo

def process_append_queue(append_queue, bar):
    while True:
        x = append_queue.get()
        if x is None:
            break
        bar.append(x)
    print("worker done")

def main():
    import multiprocessing as mp
    bar = Test()
    append_queue = mp.Queue(10)
    append_queue_process = mp.Process(target=process_append_queue, args=(append_queue, bar))
    append_queue_process.start()

    for i in range(100):
        append_queue.put(i)
    append_queue.put(None)
    append_queue_process.join()

    print str(bar.get())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

When you call `bar.get()` at the end of the `main()` function why does it still return an empty list? How can I make it so that the child process also works with the same instance of `Test` not a new one?

All answers appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, processes have distinct address spaces, so that mutations of an object in one process have no effect on any object in any other process.  Interprocess communication is needed to tell a process about changes made in another process.

That can be done explicitly (using things like `multiprocessing.Queue`), or implicitly if you use a facility implemented by `multiprocessing` for this purpose.  For example, a great deal of work is done under the covers to make changes to a `multiprocessing.Queue` visible across processes.

The easiest way in your specific example is to replace your `__init__` function like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    import multiprocessing as mp
    self.foo = mp.Manager().list()
```

It so happens that an `mp.Manager` instance supports a `list()` method that creates a process-aware list object (really a proxy for a list object, which forwards list operations to an under-the-covers server process that maintains a single copy of "the real" list - the list object isn't really shared across processes, because that's impossible - but the proxies make it *appear* to be shared).

So if you make that change, your code will display the results you expect - and there is no simpler way.

Note that multiprocessing works better the less IPC (interprocess communication) you need, and that's true pretty much regardless of application or programming language.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are copied between processes by pickling them and passing the string over a pipe. There is no way to achieve true "shared memory" for pure Python objects between processes. To achieve precisely this type of synchronization, take a look at the `multiprocessing.Manager` documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) which provides you with examples about synchronized versions of common Python container types. These are "proxied" containers where operations on the proxy send all arguments across the process boundary, pickled, and are then executed in the parent process.